# Migrating Small App to High Replication Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The current [recommendation from google](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/05/app-engine-150-release.html) is that all apps start migrating to the high replication datastore. My app is small and still in development. My [understanding](http://neogregious.blogspot.com/2011/04/migrating-app-to-high-replication.html) is that the more data my app accumulates the more involved the transition process will be. So I've decided to migrate ASAP (while I still only have 56k of user data).

I followed the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Downloading_and_Uploading_All_Data) on downloading all data from a master-slave app. I have the downloaded data. I have deployed my app to high replication. When I try to use the upload command (from the same section in the documentation) however I get an error. Here's what I'm trying to run:

```
C:\Users\Hank\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\hanksandbox>appcfg.py upload_data --application=essayhost --kind=User --filename=sandboxed .
```

and the error I get:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastore\datastore_rpc.py", line 1048, in check_rpc_success raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
google.appengine.api.datastore_errors.BadRequestError: app s~essayhost cannot access app essayhost's data
```

That's the last line of a very long traceback. If you need more let me know. If you know of a good, thorough, walkthrough for this process please link it. Most of what I'm finding is a little out of my depth.

P.S. Anyone know how to upload *all* kinds at once?

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the fix is to specify the full app id for your high replication app in the --application flag. In your case the full app id is: s~essayhost. App Engine tries to hide the s~ prefix, but doesn't always succeed.

Comment: I thought something like that might help. When I try it I get an Authentication Failed message.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue as you. This is how I fixed it:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --config-file=bulkloader.yaml --filename=links.csv --kind=Link --application=s~myapp --url=http://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
```

I'm currently migrating my data from my VPS to Google App Engine, 60k rows of data.

Edit: You can't migrate all kinds at once; you could try making a batch script or something to do it for you, but it's not that hard to type it all.